# How to create a concise SQL 'Check Constraint' that disallows certain chars for all string fields?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-express, check-constraints

I have a SQL (SQL Server Express 2008) Table that contains a handful of `VARCHAR` fields.

I would like to create a `Check Constraint` which will make sure that none of the `VARCHAR` values contain certain characters.

**Example:** (Do not allow **<**, **>**, or **?** characters in the FirstName and LastName columns)

```
(NOT [FirstName] LIKE '%<%' 
AND NOT [FirstName] LIKE '%>%' 
AND NOT [FirstName] LIKE '%?%')
AND 
(NOT [LastName] LIKE '%<%' 
AND NOT [LastName] LIKE '%>%' 
AND NOT [LastName] LIKE '%?%')
```

The SQL syntax above works fine, but it would be nice if there was shorthand way of doing the same thing. *Notice the redundancy in the example. This is cumbersome if I want to add more columns and/or invalid characters*

It would be nice if we could do something like this:

```
NOT FirstName,LastName LIKE IN ('<','>','?')
```

Is it possible for me to do something like this in a `Check Constraint` expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
NOT ([FirstName]  LIKE '%[<>?]%' OR [LastName]  LIKE '%[<>?]%')
```

Answer (score 1):

alter `table nom_table`, you should add `constraint ck check(firstname not like '%[<,>,?]%')`.